# Why is VkShaderStageFlagBits a bitmask?

Tags: graphics, bit-manipulation, bit, vulkan, bitmask

In Vulkan you specify the `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo`'s to the `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo` structure, and presumably there is supposed to be one `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo` for each shader stage (for example the vertex, and fragment shaders).

So why exactly is the field `stage` field of type `vkShaderStageFlagBits` is this just because it sits closer to some kind of Vulkan convention?

My confusion is I am led to believe that the only reason you would use a Bitmask in this way, is if you need to combine bits together. (For example for the general `flags` field in all Vulkan structures). I was trying to find the answer for this, so I looked at the Vulkan Spec, and this confused me even more! This is because they have two bits `VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS` and `VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL` these are defined as:

> VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS is a combination of bits used as shorthand to specify all graphics stages defined above (excluding the compute stage).
>
> VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL is a combination of bits used as shorthand to specify all shader stages supported by the device, including all additional stages which are introduced by extensions.

Well if they are supposed to be "shorthand" for specifying all bits, does this mean one shader stage, is supposed to be able to represent a version of all the stages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exactly, this is mostly to keep the api consistent. VkShaderStageFlagBits is used in several spots where a bit mask makes more sense than at pipeline creation time.

An example where it makes sense are descriptor set layout bindings where you use the flag mask to specify what stages can access your descriptors (samplers, uniform buffer object, etc.).

So if you want one UBO to be accessible from the vertex and fragment stage and another one from the geometry and tessellation stage you'd use different stage flag bit combinations when setting up the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`. Pipeline state combinations are pretty common here.

Comment: ahhhh, see that makes sense, because I haven't learned about Pipeline layout or Descriptor sets yet. Thanks for the samples ;)!!

Answer (score 4):

Vulkan uses fields of type `Vk*FlagBits` (e.g. `VkShaderStageFlagBits`) when exactly one of the defined values is expected, and uses the corresponding `Vk*Flags` type (always a typedef for `VkFlags` which is just a typedef for `uint32_t` (e.g. `typedef VkFlags VkShaderStageFlags`) when a combination zero, one, or more of the defined values is expected.

There are two reasons for this:

1. It gives a signal (albeit subtle) about whether exactly one value is expected/allowed or some combination of values is expected.
2. Many compilers will give warnings when assigning a combination of bit values to a field of enum type, which in practice helps enforce (1). This is because to do bitwise operations on enum values, they're first promoted to an integer type, and the result is an integer type, and typical settings for most compilers yield a warning (often promoted to error) when doing an implicit conversion from integer to enum type, since the integer may not be one of the enumerated values.

So `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo::stage` is `VkShaderStageFlagBits` because exactly one shader stage is valid there, and you'll probably get a warning if you try to set it to something silly like `VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT`.

But `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::stageFlags` is `VkShaderStageFlags` because it's common and expected to include multiple stages there, and you won't get a compiler warning if you set it to `VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT`.

Comment: I believe you meant `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo::stage` and not `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo::flags`

Comment: Woops, yes, fixed.