# Compute shader in vulkan raytracing

Tags: graphics, nvidia, vulkan, raytracing, compute-shader

I posted this question on [vulkan forums](https://community.khronos.org/t/using-tensor-cores-and-rt-cores/108248) and [NVIDIA forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/using-tensor-cores-and-rt-cores/202559). Due to lack of responses, I tried to modify the [ray tracing example](https://nvpro-samples.github.io/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/) by repurposing the closest hit shader to also act as a compute shader

```
  VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo stage{VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO};
  stage.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_CLOSEST_HIT_BIT_KHR;
```

I get the following validation error due to this

```
 vkCreateRayTracingPipelinesKHR: value of pCreateInfos[0].pStages[3].stage contains multiple members of VkShaderStageFlagBits when only a single value is allowed The Vulkan spec states: stage must be a valid VkShaderStageFlagBits value
```

I have the following questions regarding this

1. Does the closest hit shader need the `VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT` value to use cooperative matrices?
2. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51696847) clarifies that multiple values cannot be set for the `stage` attribute. Does this mean that what I am trying to do is not possible by design?

Note : I am very new to vulkan and still learning it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I never used  `VK_NV_cooperative_matrix` extension.

> Does the closest hit shader need the `VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT` value to use cooperative matrices?

I think you misunderstood the purpose of `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo::stage` : it **does not give any property to anything**. It **specifies at which stage of the pipeline** the `module` is used.  So what you are trying to do **cannot** possibly work. No shader needs any `VkShaderStageFlagBits`. The shader probably does not even know it's called from Vulkan. But Vulkan needs to know when to call the shader.

Moreover, ray tracing shaders are invoked in a `VkPipeline` that has been created using `vkCreateRayTracingPipelinesKHR` (or its `NV` equivalent).
But compute shaders are invoked in one created by `vkCreateComputePipelines`. Those are COMPLETELY different things:

[image]

**Image source:** [Introduction to Real-Time Ray Tracing with Vulkan - NVIDIA Developer blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/vulkan-raytracing/)

This image compares classical rasterization pipelines (created with `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`) and ray tracing ones, but you get the idea.

---

> I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51696847) clarifies that multiple values cannot be set for the `stage` attribute. Does this mean that what I am trying to do is not possible by design?

I do not really understand what you mean by  `"what I am trying to do"` (mainly because of your first sentence) so:

- If you mean *"giving two stages to `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo`*, the answer is **yes, it's impossible** (at least as of Vulkan 1.3).
- If you mean *"make a closest-hit shader act like a compute shader"*, the answer is again **yes, it's (probably) impossible**, but not for the same reason.
  You are likely to have ray-tracing dedicated functions that simply won't compile if you tell `glslang` *"make me compute shader out of that thing"*.
- If on the other hand you mean *"use cooperative matrices in closest-hit shaders"*, **I don't really know**. But I think there should not be any problem using them.
  [The extension description](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_NV_cooperative_matrix.html) says the following (emphasis mine):

> [...] Cooperative matrix types are medium-sized matrices that are **primarily supported in compute shaders**, where the storage for the matrix is spread across all invocations in some scope (usually a subgroup) and those invocations cooperate to efficiently perform matrix multiplies.[...]

If I understand that correctly, it does not mean it is not supported in other types of shaders. Just that it is mainly used (and thus supported) in compute shaders. Again, I've never used that extension so I may be wrong.

Note that it's a device extension, it needs to be manually enabled upon creation of the logical device (`VkDevice`).
You will also need to add a `#extension GL_NV_cooperative_matrix : enable` at the top of the shader using it.

---

That said, do you *really* need those cooperative matrices in your closest-hit shader? What performance gain will you have by having them? Keep in mind that your closest hit shader is called at EACH intersection. Looking at the code you posted on the Vulkan forums, I believe your approach will make you loose more than what you could gain.

Comment: thanks for the reply. `your approach will make you loose more than what you could gain.` You are probably right. I am mostly doing this for a school project to explore certain things. 

Also, looks like we can do ray tracing in a compute shader using the rayquery extension (since it can be used in any shader stage). With that it might be possible to use cooperative matrices and do ray tracing in a single compute shader (for what it's worth).